# BULK INSERT from comma delimited string

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I have a table with the following data in one column:

```
abc,2,2,34,5,3,2,34,32,2,3,2,2
def,2,2,34,5,3,2,34,32,2,3,2,2
```

I want to take this data and insert it into another table, using the commas as delimiters, just like how you can specify the `FIELDTERMINATOR` in `BULK INSERT` statements.

Is there a way to do this using T-SQL?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `Split` function to split your string into a table variable, and then insert those values into your table.

There are **tons** of those split functions out there, with various pros and cons and various number of parameters and so forth.

[Here is one that I quite like](https://web.archive.org/web/20120902003525/http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) - very nicely done, clearly explained.

With that function, you should have no trouble converting your column into individual entries for your other table.

Comment: Thanks.  I"m gonna look into this some more.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to split the string into columns rather than rows.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is any direct way to do in the T-SQL , but if you want to use Bulk Insert you can use `sqlcmd` to export to CSV file and then Import the file back into server using Bulk Insert.

Create a `dbo.Split` Functionm, you can refer here [split string into multiple record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)
There are tons of good examples.

if you want to execute as batch process, You can execute `sqlcmd` and 'Bulk Insert'

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select dbo.Split(col1) from SomeTable" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700

-s"," sets the column seperator to 

bulk insert destTable
from "MyData.csv"
with 
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Otherwise, You can manipulate directly in the T-SQL, but given you have the same identify of columns definition.

```
 INSERT INTO DestinationTable
 SELECT dbo.Split(col1) FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought about doing this after giving it some more thought.  Going to try the split function first and then see if I need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: allow multiple char separators

This is how I solved it, with two functions to do the splitting into columns (if you want a more complete solution with line splitting as well, [see my other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514202/how-to-pass-string-to-bulk-insert-instead-of-file/45176375#45176375)). It involves:

- A scalar function (`fSubstrNth`) for extracting the n-th field of a line, given an separator
- A scalar function (`fPatIndexMulti`) for finding the n-th index of the separator
- (Optional) alternative `Right` function to accept negative values
- Finally, some specific code to use in your solution, since SQL doesn't allow dynamic table-function definitions (in other words, you can't `SELECT` from a function with dynamic columns)

Now, for the code snippets:

**fSubstrNth**

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Bernardo A. Dal Corno
-- Create date: 18/07/2017
-- Description: substring com 2 PatIndex limitando inicio e fim
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION fSubstrNth
(
  @Text varchar(max),
  @Sep varchar(3),
  @N int --Nth campo
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(max)

  IF @N<1 RETURN ''
  IF @N=1
    SET @Result = substring(@Text, 1, dbo.fPatIndexMulti(@Sep,@Text,1)-1)
  ELSE
    SET @Result = substring(@Text, dbo.fPatIndexMulti(@Sep,@Text,@N-1)+LEN(@Sep), CASE WHEN dbo.fPatIndexMulti(@Sep,@Text,@N)>0 THEN dbo.fPatIndexMulti(@Sep,@Text,@N)-dbo.fPatIndexMulti(@Sep,@Text,@N-1)-LEN(@Sep) ELSE LEN(@Text)+1 END)

  RETURN @Result
END
```

**fPatIndexMulti**

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Bernardo A. Dal Corno
-- Create date: 17/07/2017
-- Description: recursive patIndex
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fPatIndexMulti]
(
  @Find varchar(max),
  @In varchar(max),
  @N tinyint
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @lenFind int, @Result int, @Texto varchar(max), @index int
  DECLARE @i tinyint=1

  SET @lenFind = LEN(@Find)-1
  SET @Result = 0
  SET @Texto = @In
  WHILE (@i <= @N) BEGIN
    SET @index = patindex('%'+@Find+'%',@Texto)
      IF @index = 0 RETURN 0
    SET @Result = @Result + @index
    SET @Texto = dbo.xRight(@Texto, (@index + @lenFind)*-1)

    SET @i = @i + 1
  END
  SET @Result = @Result + @lenFind*(@i-2)

  RETURN @Result
END
```

**xRight**

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Bernardo A. Dal Corno
-- Create date: 06/01/2015
-- Description: Right inverso (para nros < 0)
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[xRight] 
(
  @Texto varchar(8000),
  @Qntd int
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(8000)

  IF (Len(@Texto) = 0) OR (@Qntd = 0)
    SET @Result = ''
  ELSE IF (@Qntd > 0) 
      SET @Result = Right(@Texto, @Qntd)
    ELSE IF (@Qntd < 0)
    SET @Result = Right(@Texto, Len(@Texto) + @Qntd)

  RETURN @Result
END
```

**Specific code**

```
SELECT 
     acolumn = 'any value',
     field1 = dbo.fSubstrNth(table.datacolumn,',',1),
     field2 = dbo.fSubstrNth(table.datacolumn,',',2),
     anothercolumn = 'set your query as you would normally do',
     field3 = (CASE dbo.fSubstrNth(table.datacolumn,',',3) WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table
```

Note that:

- `fSubstrNth` receives the n-th field to extract from the 'datacolumn'
- The query can be as any other. This means it can be stored in a procedure, tabled-function, view, etc. You can extract some or all fields, in any order you wish, and process however you want
- If used in a stored procedure, you could create a generic way of creating a query and temp table that loads the string with dynamic columns, but you have to make a call to another procedure to use the data OR create a specific query like above in the same procedure (which would make it non-generic, just more reusable)